# Java Group Separator

Tags: java, ascii

I am trying to create a text file with Group Separator, I couldn't find any syntax on how to do it.
For example, if I have two strings I need to create something like below into a text file through Java.

```
String a="HREC";
String b="ZZ";
```

and final output should appear with group separators as shown in below image

[image: Output expected]

HRECZZ

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: What is the hex value of `GS`?

Comment: @PM77-1 GS (Group Seperator) is 0x1D in ASCII.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I do not understand your closure of this Question. This Question has nothing to do with bytes as [discussed in your linked Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592000/how-to-get-the-bytes-of-a-control-character-in-java), and can be answered without manipulating octets.

Comment: @BasilBourque The accepted answers shows how to write control characters to a character stream.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel But the *question* is not a duplicate. And, the reader must dig through the Answers to discover the part that happens to be a solution here. I appreciate trying to close needless questions as duplicates; I do so often myself. But this is not such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unicode code point

Call [`Character.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)) while passing the [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepoint) of that character.

Understand that [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) is a superset of [US-ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). All the 128 characters in ASCII make up the first 128 of the 144,697 characters defined in Unicode, at code points 0-127.

For the group separator non-printable character, the decimal integer for its code point is 29.

## `\u001D`

You can write that number `29` using its hexadecimal version `1D` as an escaped Unicode code point in a `String` literal: `\u001D`.

```
"dog\u001Dcat"  // A string of seven characters.
```

## `Character.toString( 29 )`

For frequent use, define a constant.

Calling `Character.toString( 29 )` produces a `String` containing a single character, your group separator.

```
final String FILE_SEPARATOR = Character.toString( 28 ) ;
final String GROUP_SEPARATOR = Character.toString( 29 ) ;
final String RECORD_SEPARATOR = Character.toString( 30 ) ;
final String UNIT_SEPARATOR = Character.toString( 31 ) ;
```

Or make a class with statics. Here for brevity we use the two-character abbreviated names defined in ASCII.

```java
public class Ascii 
{
    static final String FS = Character.toString( 28 ) ;
    static final String GS= Character.toString( 29 ) ;
    static final String RS= Character.toString( 30 ) ;
    static final String US= Character.toString( 31 ) ;
}
```

Usage:

```
myStringBuilder.append( Ascii.GS ) ;
```

---

For those not familiar with these separator characters, see the Question, [*What are the file/group/record/unit separator control characters and their usage?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8695118/642706).

---

By the way, while researching this I discovered that Unicode also defines a character [SYMBOL FOR GROUP SEPARATOR](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/241d/index.htm) (code point 9,245) for documentation that needs to display something visibly that means the unprintable character.

Comment: You can also use `"\u001D"` for GS, etc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I added a mention of that string literal approach. Thanks.