# Stop comma in csv row from splitting the column in two Java

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader, double-quotes

Here is my code

```
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sr));
      String splitBy = ",";
      String line = br.readLine();
      while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        String[] b = line.split(splitBy);
        System.out.println("\"" + b[0] + "\",\"" +b[4] + "\",\""+ b[6] + "\"");
      }
      br.close();
    }
  }
```

The columns in my csv file should print out like this

```
"John", "Smith", "Smith,John"
```

but it takes the comma in the column and splits it into two columns like this;

```
""Smith" John"", "John", "Smith"
```

How can I get it to ignore the column that is in the column and not split it into two columns AND stop it from adding double quotes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a proper CSV parser instead of trying to write your own. There are many parsers to choose from, e.g. [Jackson-databind-csv](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/2.14/csv), [Univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/about-parsers), [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/dependency-info.html) and [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: Also, for your use case, I wouldn't bother writing a program. Just install the excellent [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and use the `csvcut` command which will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have commas in your data rows then change your separator. Use `;`. There is no way for the program to know when to skip the delimiter and when not...

CSV can have any separator that you find suitable (some use `:`, `@`, `;`, `|`, etc..)

Comment: ASCII and Unicode define specific characters for use as delimiters: field is code point 31, record is 30, group of records is 29, and table/file is 28. See [*What are the file/group/record/unit separator control characters and their usage?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8695118/642706). `String fieldDelimiter = Character.toString( 31 ) ;`

Comment: Would my answer count as correct though? Thank you for the comment. Very informative. @BasilBourque

Comment: Yes, I would say this Answer is correct in a way, thus my up-vote. But it depends on how the problem is defined. Using a COMMA between field-developing QUOTATION MARK characters is the canonical delimiter, thus the name *Comma*-Separated Values (CSV). So really such input as given in the Question should be parsed as CSV, without the need for a substitute delimiter as you suggest. But as a shortcut, instead of building or using a proper CSV parser, your suggestion would work.

Answer (score 1):

Do not split by COMMA first. You must first split by the pairs of QUOTATION MARK enclosing each field. See the [CSV specification](https://csv-spec.org/).

I recommend you make use of an existing **CSV parsing library** rather than write your own. You have a choice of several good libraries in the Java ecosystem. For example, I have used [*Apache Commons CSV*](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/index.html) in a few projects. More libraries are mentioned in [this Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71221131/stop-comma-in-csv-row-from-splitting-the-column-in-two-java/71225181#comment125891681_71221131).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your regex to split on all comma characters unless it's in between quotes.

```
String[] b = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

See the acepted answers in these posts:

[Java: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring commas in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757065/java-splitting-a-comma-separated-string-but-ignoring-commas-in-quotes)

[Splitting on comma outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893390/splitting-on-comma-outside-quotes)